# Text editor error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For some strange reason I my text editor (Microsoft Visual Code) wont review this file. So you please try copy paste this in to your editor and tell me what went wrong?

Sorry for the length of the code and thank you in advance.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Space Trip - Adventure of a Lifetime</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="welcomeText">
            <div class="welcome">
                <h1 class="greet">Space Trip - Adventure of a Lifetime</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="subText">
                <div class="subTexts">
                    <p class="subscribe">Subscribe to our newsletter</p>
                    <p class="soon">We are launching soon</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form">
            <form action="" class="sub">
                <input class='email' type="email">
                <button class="button" value="Send">Get Started</button>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="social">
            <div class="follow">
                <p class="followUs">Or follow us</p>
            </div>
            <div class="socialIcons">
                <div class="socialIcon facebook brandico-facebook-rect"></div>
                <div class="socialIcon  twitter brandico-twitter-bird"></div>
                <div class="socialIcon  github brandico-github"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

@import url(http://weloveiconfonts.com/api/?family=brandico);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Junge);
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background: url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/26206/pexels-photo.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: Junge, georgia;
    text-align: center;
}


/* brandico */

[class*="brandico-"]:before {
    font-family: 'brandico', sans-serif;
}

.content {
    max-width: 40%;
    max-height: 50%;
    margin: 100px auto;
}

.welcomeText,
.form,
.social {
    width: 100%;
}


/*welcome text*/

.welcome {
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.greet {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    transition: all .5s;
}


/*taglines*/

.subText {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.subText p {
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}

.subTexts {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all .5s;
}


/*FORM*/

.form {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

.sub {
    width: 90%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: auto;
    opacity: 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4), 0 0 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    transition: all .5s;
}

.email {
    width: 70%;
    height: 70%;
    margin: 1% 0;
    padding-left: 10px;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    font-size: 20px;
}

input:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.button {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0 50px 50px 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: red;
    background-color: #49afcd;
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #5bc0de, #2f96b4);
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .5s;
}

.button:hover {
    background: #2f96b4;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}


/*footer-follow us*/

.follow {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.followUs {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
    transition: all .5s;
}

.socialIcons {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.socialIcon {
    width: 33.33%;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 100px;
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 100px;
    transition: margin-top .5s, color .5s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.socialIcon:hover {
    color: #49afcd;
    text-shadow: 0 0 20px white;
}

.twitter {
    transition-delay: .5s, 0;
}

.github {
    transition-delay: 1s, 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width:930px) {
    .subTexts p {
        font-size: 20px
    }
    .button {
        font-size: 12px
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
    .welcome,
    .subText,
    .sub {
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
    }
    .welcome {
        border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
    }
    .subText {
        border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
    }
    .sub {
        border: 1px solid;
    }
    .greet {
        font-size: 30px
    }
    .subTexts p {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    .button {
        font-size: 8px;
        margin-right: -3%
    }
}


window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var welcome = document.querySelector('.greet'),
        subtext = document.querySelector('.subTexts'),
        form = document.querySelector('.sub'),
        follow = document.querySelector('.followUs'),
        social = document.querySelectorAll('.socialIcon'),
        delay = 1000;


    setTimeout(function() { welcome.style.top = '0'; }, delay);
    setTimeout(function() { subtext.style.bottom = '0%'; }, delay * 2);
    setTimeout(function() { subtext.style.bottom = '-100%'; }, delay * 4);
    setTimeout(function() { form.style.opacity = '1'; }, delay * 5);
    setTimeout(function() { follow.style.bottom = '0%'; }, delay * 6);
    setTimeout(
        function() {
            social[0].style.marginTop = '0px';
            social[1].style.marginTop = '0px';
            social[2].style.marginTop = '0px';
        }, delay * 7
    );

});
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "review" this code. Did you mean to mix HTML, CSS, and JavaScript all into one file?

Comment: Hi Mike C, sorry for the late response...originally I have all in separate are saved in there own files and linked in the html file. The issue what I'm facing is upon reviewing the file, it's completely different i.e css is totally missing and the java script as well. I reached out to stack overflow to see if other people will experience the same problem that I have in the document. I've looked at the css and java and found that they are at least in my view clean....so it made me wonder if the problem itself is in my text editor which is microsoft visual code.

Comment: Did you plug the code into your text editor and if so what kind of results did you get?

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by review. Is the code not showing up correctly in your editor?

Comment: Yes it is, sorry for being unclear :). Did you copy paste the code into your text editor?

Comment: Sure, I can look the code just fine. It won't run correctly since you've mixed all of the languages together but I can read it just fine

Comment: Okay, to get the code to run correctly...would you suggest I put java in a separate folder like the css and linking it with href. Liking it like "<link href= javascript/style.js" rel="stylesheet">"??

Comment: I think you need to run through some basic JS tutorials. You add CSS files with `<link>` and you add JS files with `<script src="my-file.js"></script>`.

Comment: That I'll do. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Space Trip - Adventure of a Lifetime</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>


    @import url(http://weloveiconfonts.com/api/?family=brandico);
    @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Junge);
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    html,
    body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    body {
        background: url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/26206/pexels-photo.jpg') no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        font-family: Junge, georgia;
        text-align: center;
    }


    /* brandico */

    [class*="brandico-"]:before {
        font-family: 'brandico', sans-serif;
    }

    .content {
        max-width: 40%;
        max-height: 50%;
        margin: 100px auto;
    }

    .welcomeText,
    .form,
    .social {
        width: 100%;
    }


    /*welcome text*/

    .welcome {
        height: 100px;
        position: relative;
        border-bottom: 1px solid;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .greet {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        font-size: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 100px;
        transition: all .5s;
    }


    /*taglines*/

    .subText {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        position: relative;
        font-size: 30px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .subText p {
        height: 100%;
        line-height: 100px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .subTexts {
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: all .5s;
    }


    /*FORM*/

    .form {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        position: relative;
    }

    .sub {
        width: 90%;
        height: 50px;
        margin: auto;
        opacity: 0;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 50px;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4), 0 0 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
        transition: all .5s;
    }

    .email {
        width: 70%;
        height: 70%;
        margin: 1% 0;
        padding-left: 10px;
        background: none;
        border: none;
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    input:focus {
        outline: none;
    }

    .button {
        width: 20%;
        height: 100%;
        float: right;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 0 50px 50px 0;
        font-size: 16px;
        background: red;
        background-color: #49afcd;
        background-image: linear-gradient(top, #5bc0de, #2f96b4);
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: all .5s;
    }

    .button:hover {
        background: #2f96b4;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    }


    /*footer-follow us*/

    .follow {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .followUs {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 100%;
        line-height: 100px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 40px;
        transition: all .5s;
    }

    .socialIcons {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .socialIcon {
        width: 33.33%;
        height: 100px;
        float: left;
        margin-top: 100px;
        font-size: 50px;
        line-height: 100px;
        transition: margin-top .5s, color .5s;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .socialIcon:hover {
        color: #49afcd;
        text-shadow: 0 0 20px white;
    }

    .twitter {
        transition-delay: .5s, 0;
    }

    .github {
        transition-delay: 1s, 0;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width:930px) {
        .subTexts p {
            font-size: 20px
        }
        .button {
            font-size: 12px
        }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width:600px) {
        .welcome,
        .subText,
        .sub {
            background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
        }
        .welcome {
            border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
        }
        .subText {
            border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
        }
        .sub {
            border: 1px solid;
        }
        .greet {
            font-size: 30px
        }
        .subTexts p {
            font-size: 16px;
        }
        .button {
            font-size: 8px;
            margin-right: -3%
        }
    }
</style>
<script>

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var welcome = document.querySelector('.greet'),
        subtext = document.querySelector('.subTexts'),
        form = document.querySelector('.sub'),
        follow = document.querySelector('.followUs'),
        social = document.querySelectorAll('.socialIcon'),
        delay = 1000;


    setTimeout(function() { welcome.style.top = '0'; }, delay);
    setTimeout(function() { subtext.style.bottom = '0%'; }, delay * 2);
    setTimeout(function() { subtext.style.bottom = '-100%'; }, delay * 4);
    setTimeout(function() { form.style.opacity = '1'; }, delay * 5);
    setTimeout(function() { follow.style.bottom = '0%'; }, delay * 6);
    setTimeout(
        function() {
            social[0].style.marginTop = '0px';
            social[1].style.marginTop = '0px';
            social[2].style.marginTop = '0px';
        }, delay * 7
    );

});
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="welcomeText">
            <div class="welcome">
                <h1 class="greet">Space Trip - Adventure of a Lifetime</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="subText">
                <div class="subTexts">
                    <p class="subscribe">Subscribe to our newsletter</p>
                    <p class="soon">We are launching soon</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form">
            <form action="" class="sub">
                <input class='email' type="email">
                <button class="button" value="Send">Get Started</button>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="social">
            <div class="follow">
                <p class="followUs">Or follow us</p>
            </div>
            <div class="socialIcons">
                <div class="socialIcon facebook brandico-facebook-rect"></div>
                <div class="socialIcon  twitter brandico-twitter-bird"></div>
                <div class="socialIcon  github brandico-github"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'd say it's more likely that OP is meant to put his code into the referenced `index.js` and `css/style.css` files, personally.

Comment: it is a better approach, yeah. But his IDE didn't review the js and css part of the file cause he pasted the js and css without tags, so the solution specifically is to add tags. Then if the code gets bigger, move it to other files.